# Power consumption in Windows 10 and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, power-supply, power

How does Windows 10 compute the percentages of power used by various applications and hardware devices without any external power measurement device?

[image: Windows 10 Power usage screen]

It's a fascinating problem to be able to calculate the values simply from software. How does PowerTop (on linux) make these calculations to get the power consumption values in Watts? How reliable/accurate are these numbers?

[image: PowerTop screenshot]

Comment: Windows 10 has the [Energy Estimation Engine that calculates the Power Usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-157-Energy-Estimation-Engine-E3)

Comment: Any research papers or references which detail the power measurement methods would be very helpful.

Comment: the link gives some details. it also includes 2 links to Microsoft Hardware conference slides with details.